# finding parent in the callback

Tags: jquery

I've two login forms with different ids(#user-login and #user-login-form).

The form elements within them have the same id's. For attaching onlick callback how to get the val() value from whichever called parent?( ie from ("#user-login #edit-name or ("#user-login-form #edit-name)

```
jQuery('#user-login #edit-submit, #user-login-form #edit-submit').click(

 function(){
 var login = jQuery("#user-login #edit-name").val(); //need #edit-name value from whichever form it is called
```

Unfortunately I tried Google but nothing useful came up with this query.

Here is the html code:

```
<form action="/my/node?destination=node" method="post" id="user-login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
      <label for="edit-name">Username <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="15" maxlength="60" class="form-text required">
      <div class="description">please full name ending with</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
      <label for="edit-pass">Password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <input type="password" id="edit-pass" name="pass" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
    </div>
    <div class="item-list"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-8-F0WIjwGaSckitaooI93RGSdaM_WVUE65XaMkn6hy4">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_login_block">
    <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
      <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Log in" class="form-submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post your html part.

Comment: is it immediate parent to the `#edit-submit` we are talking about?

Comment: I need var login = jQuery("#user-login #edit-name").val();  and var login = jQuery("#user-login #edit-pass").val();  where #user-login can be #user-login or #user-login-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).closest('form').find('#edit-name').val()`. `this` refers to the clicked element. `.closest('form')` will find the closest `form` ancestor and `.find(...)` will find every descendant that matches the selector.

**Important:** IDs should be **unique** throughout the page. So instead of using IDs for the elements, use classes.

---

I recommend to read the **jQuery tutorial** to learn more about [event handling basics](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/) and [DOMtraversal](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/).